# Restore/synchronize Messages history

Tags: iphone, backup, messages, restore

Is there a good way to "force-synchronize" the Messages history between two Apple devices?  My iPhone was stolen, so I had to restore from an out-of-date backup (I know, I know), and this means there are text messages in the history on my computer that aren't on my phone.  Is there a good way to copy the text messages from the intervening period from my laptop to my phone?

Comment: desecration of a corpse ... but maybe this is still an issue. If those text messages are stored on a Mac there is some chance to get those synchronized via iCloud

Comment: pallox: If you have an answer, go for it.  Even if it doesn't help me, it might help someone!

Answer (score 1):

**On your iPhone:**

1. Open settings
2. At the top tap your name/Apple ID
3. Tap iCloud
4. Make sure the switch next to messages is on

**On your Mac:**

1. Open Messages on from your Dock or Applications folder.
2. Click Messages in the Menu bar.
3. Click Preferences.
4. Click Accounts.
5. Click the checkbox next to Enable Messages in iCloud.
6. Click Sync Now to begin syncing your messages.

Your messages should now begin syncing.